# Shopify Webhook Delays

Tags: shopify, workflow, webhooks

We want to give customers 10% discount based on the promo code they enter on our website as they place order. While conducting a test, the first webhook triggered from Shopify as order was created, it was missing the promo tag info. So is there any way where we can delay the triggering of webhook so that when the customer enters the promo code, the webhook contains that tag information. Appreciate your thoughts on this.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose when webhooks are sent. An orders/created webhook fires when an order is created. If you examine the webhooks available to you, you will also see orders/paid and orders/updated. Even more granular, you can wait for order transactions. So you are correct in noticing a create payload might not be as complete as you need, so either look for updates, or transactions, or paid orders. They will surely have your discount code. You have to adjust your expectations appropriately, instead of trying to tame a webhook delivery.